# Upgrade from 18.10 to 19.04 with *default* Python 3.6 fails with corrupt python symlink error

Tags: apt, upgrade, python, python3

I'm trying to upgrade from 18.10 to 19.04 but getting the error:

`Your python3 install is corrupted. Please fix the '/usr/bin/python3' 
symlink.`

Note that the `/usr/bin/python3` symlink points to the `/usr/bin/python3.6` binary.

I'm aware of prior versions having to symlink back to original python if it was upgraded, but the default python of 18.10 IS 3.6, and it was not changed. Why is this script failing?

Is the upgrade script relying on python 2.7 still? What is the process to fix this and is there a way to do it without "downgrading" python away from it's default version?

Comment: But my symlink is not broken: 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 9 Oct 25  2018 /usr/bin/python3 -> python3.6

Comment: Fair enough. My previous comment cheerfully withdrawn. Try reinstalling the `python3-minimal` package, since that's what provides the relevant symlink.

Comment: unfortunately reinstalling did not help. I usually know what I'm doing, and rarely have any issues but this one has me stumped (mostly because i refuse to downgrade my local python)

Answer (score 2):

What fixed this same issue for me was making /usr/bin/python point to 2.7 (instead of any python 3 version, which is what I had before). I assume the error was cryptic because what it thought was python2 was actually python3

```
sudo ln -sf /usr/bin/python2.7 /usr/bin/python
```

Comment: Did you have to later revert it back to 3? I just find it odd the upgrade wants python 2 while the system default is 3.x for a while.

Comment: I thought by default the system has 'python' link to python2.7 and 'python3' link to python3.6. I don't use python2 anymore so I redid the symlink to point to python3 instead, which confused the updater. Now in 19.04 the default seems to be python3.7 but abandoning support for python2 is a somewhat recent decision so thats probably what made them change the default.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem when upgrading from 16.04 to 18.04 (in WSL).

This seems to be a bug in the installer. See [do-release-upgrade fails with "Your python3 install is corrupted" if /usr/bin/python points to /etc/alternatives/python](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-release-upgrader/+bug/1825655)

The workaround is:

```
sudo rm /usr/bin/python
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python2.7 /usr/bin/python
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

Comment: I have tried that actually. It didn't work for me despite a lot of common sense suggests it should have. I have resigned to waiting until 20.04 comes out in April and do a clean install.

Answer (score 1):

I could'nt comment, so i would put my suggestion here,

Try,

`sudo rm /usr/bin/python3`

`sudo ln -sf /usr/bin/python3.6 /usr/bin/python3`

Or,

As a quick fix,did you try to create sym links using `update-alternatives` for `python3`

`sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3.6 python3 /usr/bin/python3 2`

and for managing the links created

`sudo update-alternatives --config python3`

Read more on [this](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man8/update-alternatives.8.html)

Comment: I'm afraid none of this helped. I've also managed to remove and reinstall python3 but that didn't help either. As for 'atlernatives' - the update-alternatives itself says there are no alternatives to install for python. I never changed the default. It looks like a fresh install is the only way forward for me... :(