# Problem with python in Ubuntu 18.10

Tags: python, 18.10, python3

I recently upgraded to 18.10 from 18.04, but I am facing  a new problem.

When I type python, I am getting this

> Python 3.7.3 (default, Apr  9 2019, 04:56:51)
>
> [GCC 8.3.0] on linux

But when I type python3, I am getting an error

> bash: /usr/lib/command-not-found: /usr/bin/python3: bad interpreter: No such file or directory

I couldnt opem ny terminal so I changed the very first line of /usr/bin/gnome-terminal  to:

`!#usr/bin/python` from `#!usr/bin/python3` since then I am able to open my terminal.
Upon entering `sudo apt-get update` I am getting this error

```
sh: 1: /usr/lib/cnf-update-db: not found
Reading package lists... Done
E: Problem executing scripts APT::Update::Post-Invoke-Success 'if /usr/bin/test -w /var/lib/command-not-found/ -a -e /usr/lib/cnf-update-db; then /usr/lib/cnf-update-db > /dev/null; fi'
E: Sub-process returned an error code
```

No matter whether I enter

> pip

or

> pip3

I am getting this error
`bash: /usr/local/bin/pip: /usr/bin/python3: bad interpreter: No such file or directory`

I tried `sudo update-alternatives --config python3`
I got `There is only one alternative in link group python3 (providing /usr/bin/python3.6): /usr/bin/python3.7
Nothing to configure.`

But when I type `sudo update-alternatives --config python` I am getting

```
There are 2 choices for the alternative python (providing /usr/bin/python).
```

`Selection    Path                Priority   Status`
`------------------------------------------------------------`

`0            /usr/bin/python3.6   2         auto mode`

`* 1            /usr/bin/python3.6   2         manual mode`

`2            /usr/bin/python3.7   2         manual mode`

The Software&Updates and Software Updater are also not loading when I click on their icon

Comment: Can you explain what changes you made (or attempted to make, but failed) to the system-provided Python and Python3? And what you were trying to accomplish with those changes?

Comment: I was trying to upgrade to 19.04 but I got an error something like "Your python3 install is corrupted. Please fix the '/usr/bin/python3' 
symlink.

Comment: So I entered the following command(copy-pasted from the community)                                    sudo rm /usr/bin/python3                                                                                                     then sudo ln -sf /usr/bin/python3.6 /usr/bin/python3 then sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3.6 python3 /usr/bin/python3 2 and finally sudo update-alternatives --config python3

Comment: I followed this answer https://askubuntu.com/questions/1144048/upgrade-from-18-10-to-19-04-with-default-python-3-6-fails-with-corrupt-python

Comment: I ran sudo apt install --reinstall python3-minimal everything went back to normal, but still not able to upgrade to 19.04 , when I ran "sudo do-release-upgrade' I still get "Your python3 install is corrupted. Please fix the '/usr/bin/python3' 
symlink. "

Comment: After running sudo apt install --reinstall python3-minimal I didn't recieve any error when I ran pip or pip3 or python3 and also Software&Updates and Software Updater are working normal .                                                                                  But when I run sudo do-release-upgrade I still get the error Your python3 install is corrupted. Please fix the '/usr/bin/python3' symlink. "

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`python` from your command line must point to python2.7

You might have messed up your apt. Delete your symlink and replace with the default python

`sudo rm /usr/bin/python`

`sudo ln -sf /usr/bin/python2.7 /usr/bin/python`

Similarly for Ubuntu 18.10 python3 points to python3.6

`sudo rm /usr/bin/python3`

`sudo ln -sf /usr/bin/python3.6 /usr/bin/python3`

Comment: Now can I upgrade to 19.04

Comment: Try doing that and after upgrade just make sure `python` and `python3` points to the correct symlinks.