# How to fix "bad interpreter" problem when running pip3 on Ubuntu 20.04 WSL?

Tags: python, python3, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have Cygwin on Windows10 and now I've installed Ubuntu 20.04 (WSL) and all it seems fine, except for Python3.

I've intalled python3 and pip3 but when I try to use it I get the "bad interpreter" message shown below, and is pointing to the Python3 installed on Cygwin path.

```
$ python3
Python 3.8.2 (default, Apr 27 2020, 15:53:34)
[GCC 9.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
$
$ pip3 install pandas
-bash: /mnt/d/d/cygwin64/bin/pip3: /usr/bin/python3.6: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

I've tried to delete/replace symlink as mentioned in [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1145432/problem-with-python-in-ubuntu-18-10) like this, but didn't work.

```
$ sudo rm /usr/bin/python3
$ sudo ln -sf /usr/bin/python3.8 /usr/bin/python3
```

How to fix this issue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It tries to run `/usr/bin/python3.6` (note the 3.6) but You have added symlink to `/usr/bin/python3.8` (note 3.8). Maybe just run `sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python3.8 /usr/bin/python3.6` ?

Comment: Hi Michal, I did in that way because the version 3.6 is the one installed on cygwin. The version 3.8 is the one installed on Ubuntu WSL.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Why did you type `pip3 install pandas` instead of `python3.8 -m pip install pandas` ? `python3.8` in this command is the target interpreter.
- There's no need to use pip to install Pandas in Ubuntu 20.04. The python3-pandas package is in the default Ubuntu 20.04 repositories. To install it type:

  ```
  sudo apt update  
  sudo apt install python3.8 python3-pandas
  ```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried to install using `pip3 install...` because I didn't know another way to do it. And I tried what your suggested `python3.8 -m pip ...` and it worked. Now, I can run  any pf both `python3.8 -m install package` or `sudo apt install python3.8 python3-package` for any package I want?

Comment: Now you can install Python packages with either `python3.8 -m pip install package` or `sudo apt install python3-package` for any package you want. Please search for the Python package with `apt search package` first before you try installing it with pip. Whatever packages you install with apt will also be automatically updated.

Comment: Excellent. Thanks so much for your help. Have a nice day.